# MySQL query question

Tags: mysql, join, self-join

I have a database containing the route data for airlines.
Some of the attributes are sources_airport_ID, destination_airport_ID, and airline(which supports the route from source to destination).
I'm trying to self join the table to look up airlines that have the same route (in other words, same sources_airport_ID and destination_airport_ID).

I was using the query as follows:
(table name = routes)

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
  FROM routes AS t1, routes AS t2
 WHERE t1.sources_airport_ID = t2.sources_airport_ID 
   AND t1.destination_airport_ID = t2.destination_airport_ID 
   AND t1.airline != t2.airline
```

When I execute this query, I get an error saying that the maximum execution time exceeded 300 seconds. I'm not sure if I'm using the correct query for this purpose.
Can anyone help me with the query? I'm using xampp as my database.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
My primary key is ID, which is just an auto-increment value.
There are 64,114 records in routes table.

Comment: What indexes do you have on your routes table? Hopefully the source and destination IDs.

Comment: Are the fields in the where clause indexed? How many rows are there in the routes table? How many matches do you think there are likely to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using JOIN syntax:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
  FROM routes AS t1
  JOIN routes AS t2
  ON   t1.sources_airport_ID = t2.sources_airport_ID 
  AND  t1.destination_airport_ID = t2.destination_airport_ID 
  AND  t1.airline != t2.airline
```

But as suggested do make sure that the fields `sources_airport_ID, destination_airport_ID` and `airline` are indexed in the routes table.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Indexes were the real solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT r.*, count(r.sources_airport_ID) as occ 
FROM routes r 
GROUP BY sources_airport_ID, destination_airport_ID, airline
HAVING occ > 1;
```

Comment: This won't work because he wants the same routes for different airlines: `t1.airline != t2.airline` Your GROUP BY will find the same source and destination routes for the same airline. Which can be a valid query but not what the OP wants.